# How can I split a file into seperate lines in python?

Tags: python

So basically I am trying to make a program that takes names from a file in the format "Smith, Robert"
and make an output that would look like "RobeSmit, Smith, Robert, RobertSmith,  (randomly generated password)". I have it all working but it can only do one name, and I need it to do as many as there is in the file e.g: Smith, Robert
                 Boe, Joe

Here is what I have:

```
import random

def readFile():
    f_input = open("myFile.txt", "r")
    string = f_input.read()
    f_input.close
    return string

def firstFour(string):
    lastNameFour, firstNameFour = string.split(",")
    userName = (str(firstNameFour[1:5]) + str(lastNameFour[0:4]))
    return userName

def nameArrangement(string):
    lastName, firstName = string.split(",")
    names = (str(lastName)) + "," + str(firstName) + "," + str(firstName) + str(lastName)
    return names

def passwordGen():
    alphabet = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()-=_+\][|}{;?/.,<>"
    length = 7
    password = " "
    for i in range (length):
        nextChr = random.randrange(len(alphabet))
        password = password + alphabet[nextChr]
    return password

def putItTogether(userName, names, password):
    output = userName + ", " + names + ", " + password
    print (output)

def main():
    string = readFile()
    userName = firstFour(string)
    names = nameArrangement(string)
    character = passwordGen()
    putItTogether(userName, names, character)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()`
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're having problems with?  Reading from a file?  Parsing the data in the file?

Comment: Look at the documentation for readlines(). Or, try opening your file outside of your readFile method. Then, each call to readFile will return the next line of the file. All you would need to do is check for end of file.

Comment: for spliting files into lines try this:f.readlines().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's review your code and embed reading lines into it.

Change `readFile` to return all lines:

```
def readFile():
    # with is used when a resource is only needed in a certain context. 
    # we'll use it for opening files so they close automatically.
    with open("myFile.txt", "r") as f:
        return f.readlines()
```

Write `saveFile` to store processed lines in the file:

```
def writefile(lines):
    with open("myFile.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines(lines)
```

Write `processLine` to wrap processing of a single line and **return the result** (no need for `putItTogether`):

```
def processLine(line):   
    userName = firstFour(string)
    names = nameArrangement(string)
    character = passwordGen()
    return userName + ", " + names + ", " + password
```

Now apply the processing to all lines using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) (can do [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) as well), and write them back:

```
def main()
    writeFile(map(processLine, readFile()))
```

**Tip:** This isn't very general, think of a way to abstract actions from values. For example `readFile` should read a file, rather than a specific file. It should be defined as `def readFile(filename)`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You `main` function whould be :

```
def main():
    with open("myFile.txt", "r") as f:
        for string in f:
            userName = firstFour(string)
            names = nameArrangement(string)
            character = passwordGen()
            putItTogether(userName, names, character)
```